# how to inject a database context in graphql-dotnet

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, graphql-dotnet

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IServiceProvider>(c => new FuncServiceProvider(type => c.GetRequiredService(type)));
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

services.AddSingleton<Query>();
services.AddSingleton<Schema>();

services.AddGraphQL();
```

Configure

```
app.UseGraphQL<Schema>();
```

Query

```
    public class Query : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public Query(IServiceProvider resolver)
        {
            var db = resolver.GetRequiredService<Context>();

            Name = "query";
            Field<ListGraphType<Types.Note>>("notes", resolve: _ => db.Notes.AsAsyncEnumerable());
        }
    }
```

executing the GraphQL endpoint results in the following exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Models.Database.Context' from root provider.

some more details.

Comment: Why are `Query` and `Schema` Singletons?

Comment: I deduced it from [link](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/8d5b7544006902f45b818010585b1ffa86ef446b/src/AspNetCoreCustom/Example/Startup.cs#L16-L34). AddScoped works but doesn't it perform worse?

Comment: That example used singletons because it is being used in a  middlewares, which are basically singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query` and `Schema` should be scoped as well if it wants to take advantage of using a `DbContext` which is added as scoped by default.

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

services.AddScoped<Query>();
services.AddScoped<Schema>();

services.AddGraphQL()
    .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);;
```

And the `Context` should be explicitly injected

```
public class Query : ObjectGraphType {
    public Query(Context db) {
        Name = "query";
        Field<ListGraphType<Types.Note>>("notes", resolve: _ => db.Notes.AsAsyncEnumerable());
    }
}
```

Comment: You may wish to consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873249) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/238506/219835). If you use that same `db` in multiple Fields, you're going to get an exception because resolvers are executed in parallel and EFC's `DbContext` doesn't do multi-threaded queries.